# Embed Node Red into existing angular application

Tags: node.js, angular, node-red

We are planning to use Node Red as low code platform for creating workflows in our application. For that, we require that the Node-Red editor run inside our application, which customers of our app will use to create workflows for them.

I have checked one page in Node-Red docs: **["Embedding into an existing app"](https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/runtime/embedding)** but this is for express js. I am looking for an approach in which I can use node-red editor in a component and display it to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the only way to embed the editor is as an iframe, it is not packaged as a component.

You will also need to run a separate instance of Node-RED for each user as Node-RED is not multi-tenant.

There are systems to manage instances to create a true multiuser/multi-tenant environment e.g. FlowFuse (full disclosure I work for FlowFuse)